# How to identify the original HTTP request from client?

Tags: python, node.js, http

> "To display a Web page, the browser sends an original request to fetch
> the HTML document that represents the page. It then parses this file,
> making additional requests corresponding to execution scripts, layout
> information (CSS) to display, and sub-resources contained within the
> page (usually images and videos)."

The previous quote is form **MDN Web Docs** *[An overview of HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview)*

My question is: I want to identify the original request from the client, and then temporarily store the request and all subrequests made to the server, but when the client make another original request I want to replace the temporarily data with the new requests.

for example let say that I have an `html` page that when parsed by the client make additional requests to some resources on the server, when the user reload the page he is just making another original request, so the temporarily stored request data should be replaced by the new original request and its subrequests, the same happens when the client request for another `html` page.

Comment: You have used `python` and `node.js` tags, please explain if both are equally acceptable or one of them is more desired.

Comment: yes, both are equally acceptable and any language independent solution.

Comment: Check out `Referer` header in the subrequests to link them to the original request